# QTableWidget, Stop editing of QTableWidgetItem

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a QTableWidget with lots of items. I wanted to make it so that when i press the `Return` key (Same as `Qt.Key_Return`) while editing a cell, it will select and edit the next cell. However, if i call the `nextrow` function, it will not do anything, if i'm already editing a `QTableWidgetItem` already. It does work when nothing is being edited, and it will edit the selected row.

```
self.table = QTablewidget()
... # Populate widget with QTableWidgetItems

def nextrow(self, row)
    column = 1
    self.table.editItem(self.table.item(row, column))
```

I see no way to actually disable that edit mode, and it completely ignores everything from setting the text to something, disabling the edit permission, because i'm already editing it. And as far as i looked, i couldn't find any method to do it either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to capture the key press event from the QTableWidget.  To do this you will need to subclass the QTableWidget and implement the change row function from within.

```
self.table = CustomTableWidget()
... # Populate widget with QTableWidgetItems

class CustomTableWidget(QtWidgets.QTableWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        key = event.key()
        if key == QtCore.Qt.Key_Return:
            self.select_next_row()

    def select_next_row(self):
        self.setCurrentCell(self.currentRow() + 1, self.currentColumn())
        self.edit(self.currentIndex())
```

Comment: Thanks you so much. I had already subclassed it, but for god know why, you actually need to set current cell to be selected before calling the edit. The function i used to do the selection, apparently didn't work for this purpose either...